# Testing an Ember redactor component - wait to ready

Tags: ember.js

I'm writing an acceptance test which has an Ember component I wrote. The component wraps the [redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) plugin.

The relevant part of the template is

```
<label>Let's begin</label>
{{x-redactor value=lesson.intro}}
```

and the test looks something like this:

```
test('I can edit the lesson title', function() {
  visit('/');
  $('.Lesson-intro [contenteditable="true"]').html('<p>Blah</p>');

  andThen(() => {
    var lesson = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('attrs.lesson');
    equal(lesson.get('intro'), '<p>Blah</p>');
  });
});
```

The `{{x-redactor}}` component doesn't finish its initialization work in time for the test to change its value. Is there a way to fix this (or a better way to write the test)?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use `triggerEvent` to let Ember know the content had changed. This is async and ensured the plugin was ready when the assertion was reached.

Here's what I did first:

```
visit('/');

andThen(() => {
  $('.Lesson-intro [contenteditable="true"]').html('<p>Blah</p>');
  triggerEvent('.Lesson-intro [contenteditable="true"]', 'keyup');
});

andThen(() => {
  var lesson = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('attrs.lesson');
  equal(lesson.get('intro'), '<p>Blah</p>');
});
```

Then I wrapped the redactor logic into a helper:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

Ember.Test.registerAsyncHelper('fillInRedactor', function(app, selector, content) {
  var el = `${selector} [contenteditable='true']`;
  $(el).html(content);
  return triggerEvent(el, 'keyup');
});

export default {};
```

and now my test looks like this:

```
test('I can edit the lesson', function() {
  visit('/');
  fillInRedactor('.Lesson-intro', '<p>Blah</p>');

  andThen(() => {
    var lesson = App.__container__.lookup('controller:application').get('attrs.lesson');
    equal(lesson.get('intro'), '<p>Blah</p>');
  });
});
```